# Data from file not reading into array

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a 2D array into a file. On compiling, it says that readFile, the Scanner variable may be uninitialized (which I know is because the initialization is in the try catch blocks). When I set readFile to null, however, it manages to count the number of lines but skips everything else.

Do I need to close and remake the scanner and file stuff for the actual reading in of the data? Or is there another error that I'm missing somewhere?

Also, I'm aware that the code for the actual reading in of the 2d array isn't done in the code sample below, but I'm trying to make sure it reads in correctly before I do anything else.

```
//2D table example I'm trying to read in
0 1 1 0
1 0 0 0
1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0

boolean[][] relationTable;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
String fileName;
File relationFile;
Scanner readFile;
boolean error = false;
System.out.print("Please enter the name of the table file: ");
        do{
            fileName = keyboard.next();
            try
            {
                relationFile = new File(fileName);
                readFile = new Scanner(relationFile);
                error = false;
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException fnfe)
            {
                System.out.println("File was not found. Please enter a new file name:");
                error = true;
            }

        }while (error == true);

        //finds number of lines correctly
        int count = 0;
        while (readFile.hasNextLine()) 
        {
            count++;
            readFile.nextLine();  //notes the error here when not initialized
        }
        System.out.println(count); //using the example table above it prints out 4

        relationTable = new boolean[count][count];
        int i = 0, j = 0, temp = 0;

        //doesn't appear to do this section at all.
        String[] lines= new String[count]; 
        while (readFile.hasNextLine())
        {
            lines[i] = readFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(lines[i]);
            i++;

        }
```

Comment: So ... what errors do you get when compiling ?

Comment: Well, once you scanned all the way to the end of the file, that's where the scanner is positioned. If you are not allowed to use a `List`, and you need to count the lines in advance, you'll need to close and open again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // finds number of lines correctly
    int count = 0;
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();// use arrayList instead of arrays if you dont know the number of lines like we have here.
    while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
        count++;
        lines.add(readFile.nextLine()); // notes the error here when not
                                        // initialized
    }
    System.out.println(count); // using the example table above it prints
                               // out 4

    relationTable = new boolean[count][count];
    int i = 0, j = 0, temp = 0;
```

your mistake here is that you were looping using `readFile.hasNextLine()` but the file was already read and `readFile.hasNextLine()` always returned `false`

```
    // here is a loop that works even though its not needed, we could have added the print statement in the loop above.   
    for (int x = 0; x < count; x++) {
        System.out.println(lines.get(x));

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is probably a dumb question but if I change it to an arraylist can I .split() and parseInt the same way as I could using a regular array?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're already gone through all the lines in the file.

```
while (readFile.hasNextLine()) 
{
    count++;
    readFile.nextLine();  //notes the error here when not initialized
}
```

After this point, your readFile object has not more lines left. So when you reach

```
String[] lines= new String[count]; 
while (readFile.hasNextLine())
{
    lines[i] = readFile.nextLine();
    System.out.println(lines[i]);
    i++;
}
```

There are not lines left. So in order to solve your problem you have to read the file again before the second while.

```
relationFile = new File(fileName);
readFile = new Scanner(relationFile);
```